# Short story about a scientist and his "dwarf world"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a 1930's sci fi short story about a guy who knows a scientist who creates a dwarf world about five feet in diameter, and you shrink down (supposedly by reducing diameter of electron orbits) to go to the planet via one column of light and expand by the other column of light five feet away on the other side of the planet. The guy's girlfriend gets kidnapped by a dwarf planet creature who expanded, grabbed her, then shrinks back to the planet and the guy goes in an airplane shrinking down to save her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's a 1930's sci fi short story**

["The Pygmy Planet"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81546), a 1932 novelette by [Jack Williamson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Williamson); first published in [*Astounding Stories*, February 1932](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57695+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/astounding_stories_february_1932); text available at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29177).

**about a guy who knows a scientist**

> Agnes Sterling was a slender, elfish, dark-haired girl—lovely, he had thought her, on the occasions of their few brief meetings. Larry knew her as the secretary and laboratory assistant of Dr. Travis Whiting, a retired college professor known for his work on the structure of the atom. Larry had called at the home-laboratory of the savant, months before, to check certain statistics to be used for advertising purposes and had met the girl there. Only a few times since had he seen her.
>
> Now she had called him in a voice that fairly trembled with excitement—and, he thought, dread! And she had been interrupted before she had time to give him any message.

**who creates a dwarf world about five feet in diameter,**

> Two pillars of intense light, a ray of crimson flame and another of deeply violet radiance, beat straight down from a complicated array of enormous, oddly shaped electron tubes, of mirrors and lenses and prisms, of coils and whirling disks, which reached almost to the roof. Upright, a yard in diameter and almost a yard apart, the strange columns of light were sharp-edged as two transparent cylinders filled with liquid light of ruby and of amethyst. Each ray poured down upon a circular platform of glass or polished crystal.
>
> Hanging between those motionless cylinders of red and violet light was a strange-looking, greenish globe. A round ball, nearly a yard in diameter, hung between the rays, almost touching them. Its surface was oddly splotched with darker and lighter areas. It was spinning steadily, at a low rate of speed. Larry did not see what held it up; it seemed hanging free, several feet above the crystal platforms.
>
> [. . .]
>
> Despite himself, his attention was drawn back to the little globe spinning so regularly, floating in the air between the pillars of red and violet flame. Floating alone, like a little world in space, without a visible support, it might be held up by magnetic attraction, he thought.
>
> A tiny planet!

**and you shrink down (supposedly by reducing diameter of electron orbits)**

> "Go slow!" Larry pleaded again. "I don't see—Did the doctor build—create—that planet himself?"
>
> "Yes. It began with his work on atomic structure. He discovered that certain frequencies of the X-ray—so powerful that they are almost akin to the cosmic ray—have the power of altering electronic orbits. Every atom, you know, is a sort of solar system, with electrons revolving about a proton.
>
> "And these rays would cause the electrons to fall into incredibly smaller orbits, causing vast reduction in the size of the atoms, and in the size of any object which the atoms formed. They would cause anything, living or dead, to shrink to inconceivably microscopic dimensions—or restore it to its former size, depending upon the exact wave-length used.

**to go to the planet via one column of light and expand by the other column of light five feet away on the other side of the planet.**

> "It seems too wonderful!" Larry muttered. "Could Dr. Whiting actually decrease his size and become a dwarf?"
>
> "No trick at all," Agnes assured him. "All you have to do is stand in the violet beam, to shrink. And move over in the red one, when you want to grow. I have been several times with Dr. Whiting to the Pygmy Planet."

**The guy's girlfriend gets kidnapped by a dwarf planet creature who expanded,**

> Larry, watching tensely, saw a curious, bird-like something fluttering about in the red ray, *swiftly growing larger*!

**grabbed her,**

> Abruptly the machine-monster darted forward, running swiftly upon its four legs of green metal. Slender tentacles reached out toward the shuddering girl at Larry's shoulder.

**then shrinks back to the planet**

> He turned to the companion ray of violet radiance that beat straight down on the opposite side of the tiny, whirling planet. And in that motionless torrent of chill violet flame he saw them.
>
> Tiny, already, and swiftly dwindling!
>
> With green wings outspread, the machine-monster was beating swiftly upward through the pillar of purple-blue flame. And close against the crystal tube that contained its brain, was Agnes, held fast by the whip-like tentacles of glistening green metal.

**and the guy goes in an airplane shrinking down to save her.**

> "Then I guess we try a voyage in the little plane. A slim chance, maybe. But decidedly better than none!"
>
> He returned to the table, dropped on his knees, inspected the tiny airplane. A perfect miniature, delicately beautiful; its slim, small wings were bright as silver foil. Carefully, he opened the door and peered into the diminutive cabin. Two minute rifles, several Lilliputian pistols, and boxes of ammunition to match, lay on the rear seat of the plane.
>
> "So we are prepared for war," he remarked, grinning in satisfaction. "And the next trick, I suppose, is to get shrunk to fit the plane. About three inches, she said. Lord, it's a queer thing to think about!"

Comment: That is absolutely correct. Found it now. I couldn't get "dwarf" out of my mind where "pygmy" should have been.